# How to change an old commits user to a new one in RapidSVN?

Tags: svn, rapidsvn

I am using [RapidSVN](https://rapidsvn.org/) and did some commits including the creation of folders using a user account which I have since deleted, how can I change these so they are assigned to my new user account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if RapidSVN can handle this, but on the command line you'd use `svn propedit`

```
svn propedit svn:author --revprop -r REVISION_NUMBER URL_TO_REPOSITORY
```

But you'll also need a `pre-revprop-change` hook script which returns a zero exit code to enable it. Your repository admin will need to set that up.